# Extract the data in xls file using Java beans

Tags: java, javabeans

How to extract the data in xls file using Java beans. Since, I a m not familiar with beans can some one plz explain how to get the result in xls file from below code and make the system call to open the xls file.

private static String getDGrid(){
        String jsonObj=null;

```
    OppDownListBean dropDownBean = new OppDownListBean();

    List dataDDL=opptyMgmtDAO.getOppViewData();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("{\"items\":[");
    int slno=0;
    if (dataDDL != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i<dataDDL.size(); i++) {
            slno=i+1;
            odb=(OppDataBean)dataDDL.get(i);
            sb.append("{\"slno.\":" + "\"" + slno + "\"," +"\"customer\":" + "\"" + odb.getCustomerName() + "\"," + "\"programType\":"+ "\"" 
                    + odb.getProgramType() +"\"," + "\"oppoType\":"+ "\""
                    + odb.getOppType() +"\"," + "\"requestor\":"+ "\""
                    + odb.getRequestor() +"\"," + "\"oppOwner\":"+ "\""
                    + odb.getOppOwner() +"\"," + "\"primaryTSA\":"+ "\""
                    + odb.getPrimaryTSA() +"\"," + "\"market\":"+ "\""
                    + odb.getMktShortName() +"\"," + "\"geography\":"+ "\""
                    + odb.getGeoShortName() +"\"," + "\"region\":"+ "\""
                    + odb.getRegName() +"\"," + "\"country\":"+ "\""
                    + odb.getCountry()+ "\"" +  "}");
            if (i!=dataDDL.size()-1) {
                sb.append(",");


            }
        }

    }
    sb.append("]}");
    jsonObj=sb.toString();

    return jsonObj;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.
Are you trying to read from a xls file into a OppDataBean bean or are you trying to write data to a xls file

Comment: I want to write data to xsl file. Please help.

Comment: Look at my answer.
I've (server side) used Apache Poi to create (Microsoft Office based) reports/documents.  Its not pretty in my opinion but it works

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Apache Poi](http://poi.apache.org)

Also I'd recommend using a [json library](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/).